# Timeout error in fetching records from a newly created tables from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, timeout

I am experiencing a very strange issue with SQL Server. I cannot fetch data from newly created tables from a particular schema.

There are **multiple schemas** on the same server but only one of them causes the timeout error.

I am using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#` to connect to the database which causes the error.

I also use `http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/` and it's working well.

Has anyone faced the same issue or know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the query used in fetching data and also the execution plan

Comment: I am using dbeaver and it does not support execution plan feature for SQL Server yet. The query is pretty simple.     SELECT * FROM TEST1.

Comment: in c# we have a command time out property,did you set any thing similar in node.js

Comment: Yes, I did. I set it to 120 seconds. It gives me timeout error after the mentioned time period.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't an issue with SQL Server or node module of the same. It was with dbeaver.